# Change the order of admin billing address fields in WooCommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have problem with woocommerce order in admin I want the billing_address_2 show at the end of the page as exmple bellow.

can any one please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core file that is responsible to displayinng that fields is located in WooCommerce plugin under: [`includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php).

The only available and efficient hook is: [`woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php#L42).

But you will only be able to change the admin billing fields order using something like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'change_order_admin_billing_fields' );
function change_order_admin_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    global $the_order;

    $address_2 = $fields['address_2'];

    unset($fields['address_2']);

    $fields['address_2'] = $address_2;

    return $fields;
}
```

Which will give you something like:

[image]

So as you can see **you will not get the billing `address_2` field to be displayed after the transaction ID** as you wish, but only under the billing `phone` field.

---

**Addition - Showing the `billing_address_2` field before `billing_country` field**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields' , 'change_order_admin_billing_fields' );
function change_order_admin_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    global $the_order;

    $sorted_fields = [];
    $address_2 = $fields['address_2'];
    unset($fields['address_2']);

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $values ) {
        if( $key === 'country' ) {
            $sorted_fields['address_2'] = $address_2;
        }
        $sorted_fields[$key] = $values;
    }

    return $sorted_fields;
}
```

Comment: yes thank you very much my problem solved can I also show the billing_address_2 before country field?